# Dynamic variable from dom

Tags: jquery, html, json, dynamic, twig

How can I get a dynamic variable from the dom and use in in jquery? I have this in my dom:

```
<script>
    window.getArray{{ facetid }} = {{ array | json_encode | raw }};
</script>
```

In my jquery I would like something like:

```
var array = window.getArray[id];
```

How do I make this work? The {{ facetid }} is a number like: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right way to write it down:

```
array = window['getArray'+getid]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correct, but if u want to use a twig variable in jQuery do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var VARIABLE = '{{ VARIABLE_NAME }}';
</script>
```

And maybe if it is an array, use this:

```
VARIABLE = {{ VARIABLE_NAME.toArray|json_encode() }};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry if my explanation is a bit vague. The Json part is oke. the variable name is dynamic.: VARIABLE1 = array VARIABLE40 = array VARIABLE15 = array. In my jquery I have the corresponding id(1,40,15) but I cant seem to do this: window.getArray[id];

Comment: you can try reputting the numbers in variables fo jquerry and use those then it should work perfectly